# Using datasets in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have inserted a dataset to my asp.net webpage, using Add New Item >> Dataset.  I have bound it with my table in DB and also previewed data by right clicking Preview Data BUT the problem is previewing data through code.

I am quite familiar with using the datasets in vb.net but I wonder how to use them in asp.net.

I am simply tring to use through filling the TableAdapter, as

```
Me.TblSQsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsSQs.tblSQs, vrExamIDSetPaper)
```

but dsSQs (my dataset name) does not snow the table name when I press . as we do in vb.net winforms.

I want to get no. of rows that come under given parameter. e.g vrExamIDSetPaper

Plesae help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the Tables collection and then rows.

```
dsSQs.Tables(0)

dsSQs.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```

Comment: Does not work !! pressing . after my dataset does not show Tables.  If I write it, it generates error

Comment: Are you certain your sql statement in your tableadapter is bringing back results?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using below code by that name  vrExamIDSetPaper

```
dsSQs.Tables(vrExamIDSetPaper).Rows.Count// For how many rows
```

Comment: Does not work !! pressing . after my dataset does not show Tables.  If I write it, it generates error.  Tried dsSQs. and it does not accept Tables after that